# Since a class in Java cannot extend multiple classes. How would I be able to get by this?

Tags: java, class, interface, extends, implements

I have two classes that need to extend one class. I am getting a compiler error since this cannot happen in Java. I know that you can implement as many interfaces you want to in Java but can only extend one other class. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: By "I have two classes that need to extend one class" I think you mean "I have one class that needs to extend two classes."

Comment: Best if you describe exactly what you're trying to model, instead of the more general "how can I extend from two classes".

Comment: "How can I fix this problem?" it's not a problem, it's a feature :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Java - Multiple inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5003285/1164465)

Comment: Closed as not a real question, even though it has been viewed 12,109 times. SO needs to change its behavior RIGHT NOW!

Answer (score 10):

Use a "has A" relationship instead of "is An".

```
class A
class B
```

You (think) you want:

```
class C extends A, B
```

Instead, do this:

```
class C {
  A theA;
  B theB;
}
```

Multiple inheritance is almost always abused. It's not proper to extend classes just as an easy way to import their data and methods. If you extend a class, it should truly be an "is An" relationship.

For example, suppose you had classes,

```
class Bank extends Financial
class Calculator
```

You might do this if you want to use the functions of the `Calculator` in `Bank`,

```
class Bank extends Calculator, Financial
```

However, a `Bank` is most definitely NOT a `Calculator`. A Bank *uses* a `Calculator`, but it isn't one itself. Of course, in java, you cannot do that anyway, but there are other languages where you can.

If you don't buy any of that, and if you REALLY wanted the functions of `Calculator` to be part of `Bank`'s interface, you can do that through Java interfaces.

```
interface CalculatorIntf {
  int add(int a, int b);
}

class Calculator implements CalculatorInf {
  int add(int a, int b) { return a + b };
}

class Bank extends Financial implements CalculatorIntf
  Calculator c = new Calculator();

  @Override // Method from Calculator interface
  int add(int a, int b) { c.add(a, b); }
}
```

A class can implement as many interfaces as it wants. Note that this is still technically a "has A" relationship

Comment: +1 I'd like to add that you should use interfaces if you really need the dual "is a" relationship.

Comment: it depends on if you need to export the data and methods of the other class, or just consume them. if you only need to consume them, you should not make it's methods / data part of your interface (by implementing interfaces). all implemented interface methods are implicitly public.

Answer (score 1):

"Two classes that extend one class" is legal.

"One class extending two classes" is against  the specification of the language. If you do not want to consider interfaces, it cannot be done.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid [diamond problem](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/c-cplusplus/diamond-problem) Java does not support Multiple Inheritance through classes but it supports using interfaces.

So you may use `Association` Relationship. e.g.

```
Class A {}
Class B {}
Class C implements SomeInterface {
  A a;
  B b;
  // setter getter for a and b and other methods
}
```

Comment: This isn't telling the OP anything he doesn't already know.

Comment: @AndresF. : edited answer. I was providing more details.

Answer (score 0):

Two classes extending ONE class? like so:

```
class A{ }
class B extends A{ }
class C extends A{ }
```

Here, B and C(two classes) extend A(one class). 
But I am sure you meant One class extending Two separate classes(Multiple Inheritance). 
WorkAround: you could make a composite Object that has two separate objects(Has-A relationship) like so:

```
class A { }
class B { }
class C extends A { /*define new functionality here */ }
class D extends B { /*define new functionality here */ }
class E { private C cObj; private D dObj; }
```

Comment: perverting the class hierarchy in this way is almost never the right solution, and in most cases you won't have the ability to make those changes as you are consuming the super classes from a library.

Comment: The problem starts at design level. If at any point in your design, you MUST inherit from two classes, then obviously you're designing it wrong!

Comment: Not at all. If, in your domain, `E isA A` and `E isA B`, then a very logical way to model this in code is through multiple inheritance. The fact that Java doesn't support this doesn't make it "wrong", merely "inconvenient". Other languages such as Scala support this (via [traits](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/scala-for-java-refugees-part-5), in Scala's case).

Comment: @DNA I am not saying its wrong. For example a "Son" inherits from both father and mother. This is also easily seen in C++ which supports multiple inheritance. Because the question was "in Java" I had to use "Has A" relationship instead of "isA". Not saying either is right or wrong.