# Multiple Inheritance in Java and interfaces

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Can we say that multiple inheritance in Java is made possible by  implementing interfaces?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003285/how-can-interfaces-replace-the-need-for-multiple-inheritance-when-have-existing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. An interface defines how an implementation should communicate with the outside world you do not define any behavior. You can of course implement multiple interfaces but that doesn't mean that you have multiple inheritance, just that the class implementing the interfaces can appear as different things.

Answer (score 4):

With `default` methods in interfaces in `java8` we will have multiple inheritance :)

Answer (score 2):

No. You aren't really inheriting anything. You are specifying behavior.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really "multiple-inheritance", you are simply outlining what the class should be able to do.

About as close a "multiple-inheritance" goes I suppose would be interfaces extending interfaces, really.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. When you implement an interface, you are simply making a "promise" to implement certain methods in said class. When you extend another class, you inherit its methods and instance variables. Two completely separate things.