# Does really interfaces can be use to achieve multiple inheritance

Tags: java, c#, inheritance, interface, multiple-inheritance

I have this confusion for long time. Many people says we can achieve multiple inheritance by interfaces in languages like C# or Java which does not support it like C++ does. But my understanding of inheritance and interface says no. Because interfaces are contracts to validate an implementation which has nothing to do with behavior. Interface defines what something can do (not what something is). But inheritance is inheriting behavior and/or property from parents (like a child is getting some genetic behavior from his parent - which is inheritance). Now the child is learning a skills say painting and cooking and the interface (a certificate or contract) acts as a validation that the child is having such skills (that is what the child can do other than what he got from his parents - and that's not inheritance)

So am I understanding it wrong? And if not then why it is saying that we can achieve multiple inheritance using interfaces?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556652/how-do-java-interfaces-simulate-multiple-inheritance Check this link. It may help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interfaces give you multiple inheritance of a type, but not behaviour. A class implementing `List` and `Map` is a "ListMap", but the implementation has nothing (necessarily) to do with any existing `List` or `Map` implementation.

Of course using composition (which should be favored anyways), you could easily create a `ListMap` which delegates the calls accordingly to its `list` and `map` properties, while providing some presumably useful function that would combine their respective data.

With Java 8 interfaces are allowed default methods, so inheritance of behaviour is now also possible.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can create an interface for example `Animal` and an abstract class `Bird`.

then you can have a class `MockingBird` which extends the behavior of `Bird` and implements the actions of an `Animal`.

However, you can then address `MockingBird` as an `Animal` or as a `Bird` because it **"inherits"** from both.

Answer (score 0):

**No, interfaces cannot be used to achieve multiple inheritance**

Not at all in Java, in C#, we can get closer.

I studied this matter when I wanted to implement an observer, and ended up in Robert Martin's blog: http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2015/01/08/InterfaceConsideredHarmful.html

After reading this post I realized he's talking about Java, but C# supports extension methods which allow you to attach behaviour on interfaces so I tried to make my implementation on some IObservable interface but obviously failed, even if I can attach behaviour in such interfaces extension methods I'm still not allowed for attaching state on them, if some day microsoft decides to implement [extension properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/619043/1102585) then this combination (Interface + Extension methods + Extension properties) could be sufficient to truly simulate some useful multiple inheritance.

For now, we are stuck with duplicating the code, or the delegation code in all our observers as stated in the blog.