# How to make my class inherits the methods of other classes

Tags: java

I am beginner to core java. We know that multiple inheritance is not possible with classes, but my question is
In a business requirement there are two classes `C1` and `C2` already defined and given to us. Now C1 has method `m1()` and `C2` has method `m2()`. Now my class is `C3`. How to access the methods of `m1` and `m2` defined in classes `C1` and `C2` in my class `C3`,

```
C3 c3=new C3();
c3.m1();
c3.m2();
```

By creating the instance of my class I should able to access the methods in the classes given to me
Note:: Code for the classes `C1` and `C2` should not be changed and I should not create the objects of `C1` and `C2`, by creating the object of `C3` I should be able to access the methods.

Can any please help me for solving this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556652/how-do-java-interfaces-simulate-multiple-inheritance

Answer (score 2):

> Code for the classes C1 and C2 should not be changed and I should not
>   create the objects of C1 and C2, by creating the object of C3 I should
>   be able to access the methods.

Unless `C2` extends `C1` (or vice versa), this is not possible. You either need an instance of each ([composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)) or an inheritance hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

If you want multiple inheritance in your program u can use **interface** . But if you don't want to change your C1 and C2 Class so make C1 class as inner class of Interface. C1 class and its method should be static.

```
interface A
{
    static class C1
{
    static public void m1()
    {
        System.out.print("i am m1");
    }

}
}
class C2
{
    public void m2()
    {
        System.out.print("i am m2");
    }

}
public class C3 extends C2 implements A {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        C3 ob= new C3();
        A.C1.m1();
        ob.m2();
    }

}
```

Output:   i am m1
          i am m2

You can also use **multi-level inheritance**

```
class C1 
{
     public void m1()
    {
        System.out.print("i am m1");
    }

}

class C2 extends C1
{
    public void m2()
    {
        System.out.print("i am m2");
    }

}
public class C3 extends C2  {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        C3 ob= new C3();
        ob.m1();
        ob.m2();
    }

}
```

Output:   i am m1
          i am m2